# Why sometime heightForRowAtIndexPath is called before numberOfRowsInSection?

Tags: ios, tableview, realm

I have this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UnlockTableSectionHeaderType type = (UnlockTableSectionHeaderType) [self.sections[section] integerValue];
    switch (type) {
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeAllLeaderBoard:
            return 1;
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeTopic:
            NSLog(@"%@", [self.topicController showLoading] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
            NSLog(@"%d", [self.topicController loadedItemCount]);
            return [self.topicController showLoading] ? 1 : [self.topicController loadedItemCount];
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeCategory:
            return [self.categoryController showLoading] ? 1 : [self.categoryController loadedItemCount];
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [UnlockTableSectionHeaderView defautHeight];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UnlockTableSectionHeaderType type = (UnlockTableSectionHeaderType) [self.sections[indexPath.section] integerValue];
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    switch (type) {
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeAllLeaderBoard:
            return 207.0f;
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeTopic:
            NSLog(@"heightForRow %@", [self.topicController showLoading] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
            NSLog(@"heightForRow %d", [self.topicController loadedItemCount]);
            return [self.topicController showLoading] ? 130.0f :
                    [TopicCell heightForTopicCellForThread:[self.topicController itemForIndex:row] showCategory:YES];
        case UnlockTableSectionTypeCategory:
            return 120.0f;
    }
    return 0.0f;
}
```

Which try to display data with controller (`Controller` is like the one who responsible for query data from web and realm)

this is the log i have got

```
Sent message: 41|{"id":51,"m":"group.getAllUnlock","p":[{"limit":15,"skip":0}]} <-- call to server
Sent message: 41|{"id":52,"m":"thread.queryUnlock","p":[{"limit":15,"skip":0}]} <-- call to server
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
YES
0
heightForRow YES
heightForRow 0
Got response for RPC call 52, 34 bytes <-- response from server
Zip size: 838
Got response for RPC call 51, 3087 bytes <-- response from server
heightForRow NO <-- Height For Row called first
heightForRow 0
WARNING: GoogleAnalytics 3.10 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *) (GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:49): Uncaught exception: Index 0 is out of bounds (must be less than 0)
```

As you can see when I got the data from server I update result in realm and make a delegate call to this method using realm notification

```
- (void)controllerDidReloadData:(BaseController *_Nonnull)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But somehow `numberOfRowsInSection` is not called...

and it crashes at this row

```
return [self.topicController showLoading] ? 130.0f :
                    [TopicCell heightForTopicCellForThread:[self.topicController itemForIndex:row] showCategory:YES];
```

How can I solve this? 
Thanks

**UPDATE**

Now looking at the stacktrace sorry for not including it earlier and I cannot do it now because We already change the design. By removing topic out and leave only category so now we only have one type of controller and the crash is gone... Seem like it is the problem with two types of data source for each section and when one of them is update while the other still updating it result in crash.

Anyway for more information that `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is being called from this line in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
if (type == UnlockTableSectionTypeTopic) {
        if ([self.topicController showLoading]) {
            return [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([LoadingTableViewCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
        // Below line is the line which called `heightForRowAtIndexPath` when looking into the stacktrace
        TopicCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:NSStringFromClass([TopicCell class]) forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.delegate = self;
        [cell configureCellForThread:[self.topicController itemForIndex:row]
                            lastCell:row == [self.topicController loadedItemCount] - 1
                        showCategory:YES];
        return cell;
    }
```

But I don't know why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called at this time

Comment: Is the order in which the delegate methods are called defined by Apple then?

Comment: What does your `topicController` do? Especially in `itemForIndex:`? Is that delegating directly to a Realm collection? Also how do you propagate the update from the Realm notification to the view controller? Does that happen synchronously?

Comment: The log does not show when you call 'reloadData'. Probably the crash occurs before that time? It sounds very much like you have a threading problem, that you update the underlying data on a background thread.

Comment: @marius the only thing `itemForIndex:` do is `return self.items[index];` where `self.items` is `RLMResults`. This initialise in `viewDidLoad:` by querying from realm (if has, it will not show loading cell) and make a query to the server. When the result come back, it save data to realm and the realm notification on `self.items` will delegate back and called `reloadData`

Answer (score 0):

The `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` methods may be called at any time, for example during scrolling. The table view will only call `numberOfRowsInSection:` when it knows that the underlying data has changed. That's what the `reloadData` call is for: to tell the table view that the data has changed, and it needs to reinitialise the table.

Therefore, it is important that you update the underlying data (in Realm in your case) on the main thread, and call `reloadData` immediately after that.

Your `[self.topicController showLoading]` seems to be a work-around to avoid having to do that. That can work fine, but then you need to make sure that you change the `showLoading` status and call `reloadData` both on the main thread directly after each other.

Answer (score -1):

This is defined by apple. But when you think about it - it makes sense. It doesn't make sense to ask another section for the number of its rows if they take up full screen height.

Comment: It could be possibly be understandable that numberOfRowsInSection: is not called for sections that are off-screen. But then heightForRowAtIndexPath: should definitely not be called for those sections either.

Comment: The `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is called to calculate the size and position of the scrollbar at the right.

Comment: for that purpose, it certainly needs to call numberOfRowsInSection: before the heightForRowAtIndexPath:. That is, it does not make sense not to do that.

Comment: True, haven't thought this through completely.